# Scheme, how do you append a list with a single item?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a function to append a list with a  single item.  What it's doing though is returning a dot pair.

```
(define (append lst x)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) x)
    (else (cons (car lst) (append (cdr lst) x)))))
```

The output I'm getting is

```
> (append '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) 8)
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 . 8)
```

I'm trying to get

```
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (append lst x)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) (cons x '())) ; here's the change
    (else (cons (car lst) (append (cdr lst) x)))))
```

Notice that all proper lists must end in the empty list, otherwise it'll happen what you just experienced. To put it in another way:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 3))
=> '(1 2 . 3) ; an improper list

(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))
=> '(1 2 3)   ; a proper list
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use `append` there is no reason why not. It performs pretty much the same as what you are trying since `append` is O(n) where n is the number of elements in the first list. This is just less code.

```scm
;; append element to last
(define (append-elt lst x)
  (append lst (list x)))
```

Comment: Probably not allowed - this is probably CS homework where the point is to learn how to implement append (and probably required to use a DrScheme/DrRacket sub-language that doesn't have append defined).

Comment: @AndrewMedico I have a feeling it isn't allowed but I think it belongs as an answer to the question.

Comment: I've seen people name this `snoc`, i.e. `cons` reversed. [As for homework, if someone doesn't fess up in their question, tough beans. Your answer is good.]