# Dr Racket - Help making a function that adds a new element to a list

Tags: list, recursion, racket

I need help creating a function that add a new ball to the existing list.

```
Function AddBalls    
AddBalls ListOfBalls -> ListOfBalls  
This function adds one new ball to a list of balls 

(define (AddBall List)
  (...))

(define (AddBall L)
 (cond
 [(empty? L) empty]
 [(cons? L)
  (cons (first L)(AddBall(rest L))]))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to be able to add a new ball to the existing list. Create a new list with a new ball added

Comment: unfortunately i don`t know how to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheme, how do you append a list with a single item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947366/scheme-how-do-you-append-a-list-with-a-single-item)

Answer (score 1):

So I have no idea what a ball is in Racket, but you can add any element to a list quite easily. So basically it's easiest to add to front:

```
(define my-list '(2 3 4))
(define my-new-list (cons 1 my-list))
```

A procedure that does this:

```
(define (add-list e lst)
  (cons e lst))
```

But notice that it's just like `cons` with arguments in the same order so you could do just:

```
(define add-list cons)
(add-list 1 '(2 3 4)) ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

So what if you want to add to the end of the list? I'd use append:

```
(define (add-last lst el)
  (append lst (list el)))

(add-last '(1 2 3) 4) ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

To support any alements added to the end:

```
(define (add-last lst . els)
  (append lst els))

(add-last '(1 2 3) 4 5 6 7) ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
```